# How to change Omega subtheme's layout for a view

Tags: 7, views, theming

I sense this can be done with Context etc, but it doesn't feel right to issue a few more modules for the job of a few lines of code.

Something like the following has to fit this:

```
function mytheme_omega_layout_alter(&$layout) {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) 
      && $node = node_load(arg(1)) && $node->type == 'article') {
    $layout = 'article';
  }
  else if ($view = views_get_current_view() && $view
      && $view->name == 'term_content' && $view->current_display == 'term_page') {
    $layout = 'term_page';
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($view);
    print '</pre>'; 
  }
}
```

The problem here is, `views_get_current_view()` looks like it doesn't play well in this hook. I couldn't find any documentation.

I'll send best of my karma-pack to any contribution:) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow wow, little bit syntax failure with the wrong function caused a disturbance in the force.

Here is how:

```
function mytheme_omega_layout_alter(&$layout) {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) 
      && $node = node_load(arg(1)) && $node->type == 'article') {
    $layout = 'article';
  }
  else if (($view = views_get_page_view()) 
        && $view->name == 'term_content' && $view->current_display == 'term_page') {
    $layout = 'term_page';
  }
}
```

PS: This is going to the community wiki as the internets don't have an answer about it!